# PHP Does not show errors when trying to connect to a wrong database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-reporting

I'm pretty much new to PHP and I'm having a very basic problem which I haven't found a solution to despite looking through similar questions in the forum.

I'm trying to connect PHP with my database (MySQL) through PDO. If I enter a wrong username or password php does show an error in the browser but if I enter a wrong database name it doesn't retireve any errors. How is this possible? My code is as follows:

```
<?php
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:127.0.0.1;dbname=myDb','root','root');
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOexception $e){
    echo 'wrong credentials';
}
```

My php.ini file is configured to show errors and Apache was restarted after modifying it with the following values:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

I also tried to use the following code at the begining of my script but it still doesn't show errors related to a wrong database name

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I'm sure is probably a pretty stupid thing but I honestly can't figure it out.

Comment: What does `$conn->errorInfo()` show you?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Apache error log?

Comment: @RyanVincent Please go ahead and post this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This turned into quite a tricky bug to find and explain even though it is quite simple.

The issue is that the *dsn* string is incorrect.

current value: *`'mysql:127.0.0.1;dbname=myDb'`*

it should be: *`'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=myDB'`* note: *`host=`* was missing.

However, PDO does not validate the *dsn* parameter string correctly and **connects to the Localhost database without any error**.

However, it has **ignored the *`dbname`* parameter**, so that when you try a query then you get an error of: *`1046 No database selected'`*.

*Clarification of what is happening* (see Alfredo Delgado below):
   PDO is ignoring the malformed parameter completely and assuming the `Localhost` database is what you want. ;-/

As mentioned by Alfredo Delgado:

... "the resulting behavior of not having host= in the dsn was that PDO was silently defaulting to localhost. Since I happened to have a local copy of the DB I wasted hours chasing down red herrings like permissions."

Comment: This is also related to 'other issues' with PDO as regards 'PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false'. It stops exceptions being raised with certain versions of PHP and PDO. I need to check the later versions. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688740/duplicate-key-not-triggering-exception-throwing-in-pdo-for-composite-key-in-simp#comment47573307_29688740)

Comment: I so wish that people who downvote would explain why they don't like the answer. Then I can improve the answer.

Comment: I ran into this, today. The resulting behavior of not having host= in the dsn was that PDO was silently defaulting to localhost. Since I happened to have a local copy of the DB I wasted hours chasing down red herrings like permissions.

Comment: @AlfredoDelgado, you have my sympathy. ;-/ As the error report is incorrect it really is an amazing 'timesink' trying to find and explain what is actually wrong. .Updated the answer.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have DSN values as they should be```$conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $serverName; dbname = $dbName; charset = $charset", $userName, $password);```, but when I temper with dbname, the connection still succeeds. I want to have a connection to a specific database on my server.

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya, this can get so frustrating. Do you really have 'spaces' or 'unprintable' characters in you connection DSN?  You can access the database from PHPMyAdmin? Another possibility is to use an explicit 'use database <DBNAME>' command after you connect to  mysql  with PHP. I would test everything on a local database before trying with a remote database. Feel free to email me. see My Profile.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes I do have 'spaces', but are spaces regarded in those particular places in PHP programing?

Comment: @RyanViçeñte, oh yes I can access database from PHPMyAdmin!

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya I have tried spaces in the DSN and it causes errors. ;-/ Assume the PHP database DSN parser is really simple and needs the connection details exactly as shown in the manual. Remember, test the code in 'Emulates' mode. It will trap errors but may not throw exceptions.

Comment: I did that(closed up all spaces)and it worked fine. Thanks Ryan. I can't find your email or phone number I have more queries that are different and I feel that you can help me. I would love to reach you, kindly share your contact details.

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya, Glad you got it working!  At the bottom of my profile is an email address that you can use to contact me. It is real and I do check it. :) I will try and assist you when I can. :)